# Can I enable Find My (and only Find My) on an iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, icloud, find-my-iphone

I'm setting up an old iPad to act as a "smart home controller" for visitors.  (It's a few years old, but still able to run iOS 15.0.)  As part of this, I'd like to turn off iCloud, so that they don't have access to my photos, files, and other personal stuff that's on iCloud.  However, this (I think) means that "Find My" would also be disabled, and, in a perfect world, I'd like to keep that working.

Is there any way to do this?  Keeping the iPad logged into iCloud with photos etc turned off in Settings does me no good, since the visitor can just turn Photos back on, without a password.

Any thoughts out there?

Comment: Creating a separate iCloud account for this purpose is one option.

Comment: Huh.  This is probably the easiest / most pragmatic thing to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a separate iCloud account for this purpose is perhaps the only option you have.